# Intellisense is showing errors from standard library while using /std:c++latest but the project compiles fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense, c++23

I'm building a piece of software using VS2022 Community and the software is marked to use `C++23` or `/std:c++latest` in its `CMakeLists.txt`.

The software builds fine, but the "Error List" pane in VS shows two peculiar compile errors in the file `<ranges>`. These errors go away if I manually make the software build in `C++20` instead of `C++23`. Here are the errors in Error List pane and also the code responsible for them:
[image: _]
[image: __]
Because of the `#if` clause on line 43, these errors aren't present if I build with `C++20`.

Again, the software builds fine. There are no errors in the Output pane. It also works fine too. The problem I'm facing is because of these peculiar errors I can't update running code with HotReload because it thinks the code can't be compiled (as there are errors). This the message I'm getting if I try to change code and resume execution after the debugger hit a breakpoint. Clicking any of the buttons will prompt me to terminate the program in VS.

[image: ___]

How can I resolve this problem?

The obvious answer is to downgrade the compiler to C++20 but I'm only building this software for my own purposes. I'm not maintaining the code and I haven't got the privileges to do so.

Is there a way to get rid of these errors in `<ranges>` without downgrading the compiler so I can use HotReload?

Thank you for your time :)
[image: ____]

---

Before people ask, I have no idea how to post whole projects in here. So to be able to reproduce, open up a Console Application project, make it compile with C++23 and don't forget to `#include <ranges>` and see the errors for yourself. I can publish a minimal reproducible example if I can find out how to so.

Comment: *The software builds fine* -- Intellisense is not the C++ compiler, thus there is nothing to be concerned with.  Any bugs in Intellisense are just an inconvenience, but it has no bearing on whether the actual C++ compiler is functional or not.

Comment: In other words: C++ is very complicated. Only a C++ compiler fully undersdands a C++ program. A text editor with "Intellisense" is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm aware I shouldn't be concerned with Intellisense errors, and I'm not. The problem is: Because of those errors (it seems like), the HotReload doesn't work. I need HotReload to work.

Comment: As a matter of fact, many developers just disable Intellisense and/or ignore it, and concentrate on whether their application builds or not.

Comment: Intellisense *is* backed by a genuine C++ compiler. (And this is a bug in the said compiler.)

Comment: @cpplearner Which compiler backs the VS intellisense?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_Design_Group

Comment: @DogaOruc Hi, you could post the minimal reproduction example to github, and then you could put the link in the question(Don't put personal information there).

Comment: Sadly no, I can't resolve this issue. HotReload won't work without downgrading to C++20.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC uses a different compiler for Intellisense than for compiling your code.

Quite often it supports different features.  You can hack things a bit and have different preprocessor tokens in the Intellisense path by doing `#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__`.

Such as

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#undef _HAS_CXX23
#endif
```

then the only spots that generate errors will be code that uses C++23 features.  You can guard them individually.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler front end that backs Intellisense is different from the one that's used to build your program, and the former has trouble with the code pattern used in `<ranges>`. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1621#issuecomment-1751905060) and has been recorded in the internal bug tracker.

But this should have nothing to do with HotReload

Comment: HotReload to works when I switch from C++23 to C++20. In C++20 there are no errors in Error List pane. Maybe there isn't a causation but there definitely is a correlation.